# I want SQL Compact to push its data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication

I would like the data in my SQL Compact database, located on a Windows CE device, to be periodically pushed to a SQL Server instance in a remote location. How would I do that? Do I need programming skills, or is it strictly configuration?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE supports merge replication, you should be able to make use of that feature for your data syncs.  Have a look at through the following on Technet (the 2nd two are linked from the first):

- [**Introducing Merge Replication**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172407.aspx)
- [**Planning for Replication**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172431.aspx)
- [**Implementing Replication**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the reference documentation you are referring to. It seems to focus on disconnected systems, where data from a "master" SQL Server database is pushed to e.g. handheld devices with SQL Compact. What I need is for my one SQL Compact database to push its recent changes to one central SQL Server.

Comment: @Kristoffer It's a server level feature.  You configure replication on the server and tell it what it needs to replicate (ie- push).  Disconnected systems are just an example of where merge replication is useful.

Comment: So SQL Server can be configured to pull data from SQL Compact? Is that described anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 supports three methods of connecting to and exchanging data with a SQL Server database: remote data access (RDA), merge replication, and Sync Services. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171801.aspx